# Word/HTML cleanup XSLT for Rich Text Field example

Tags: 2013, filtering-xslt

Does anyone have a good, production proven XSLT for cleaning up pasted content in Rich Text Fields (Tridion 2013 SP1). I had a hunt around, could only find [this one from Bart](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/630/54) which may be good enough, but I wondered if anyone had any other good ones. I am particularly interested in ensuring that content copy-pasted from web pages and MS word documents is cleaned down to semantic/structural markup only.

Comment: Are you looking for XSLT only or GUI extension(with its own textbox) work for you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by GUI extension, but I was thinking of just a cleanup XSLT

Comment: i mean we are using GUI extension for cleanup purpose before copying it into the RTF. so it cleanup content pasted from word or html doc.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one I used a while ago (quite similair to the one before, but with a little extra ;o), it removes the `font` element and attributes like `align`, `valign`, `border`, `cellpadding`, `cellspacing`. It also removes all `style` attributes, unless they contain `text-align`, since that is what the default `table` editor uses to center align text in a cell.

The last bit of cleanup is removing `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes if their value is `1` (which is pointless ;o) and I remove some well know Microsoft Word classes like `MsoNormal` and `MsoTableGrid`

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="/ | node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
        <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
        <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- remove disallowed elements but keep its children -->
    <xsl:template match="font">
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- remove disallowed attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@align | @valign | @border | @cellpadding | @cellspacing"></xsl:template>
    <!-- remove all style attributes except those for a table cell to allow center alignment -->    
    <xsl:template match="*[not(local-name() = &apos;td&apos;)]/@style"></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="td/@style">
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,&apos;text-align&apos;)">
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:text>text-align:center;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- remove rowspan and collspan when set to 1 -->
    <xsl:template match="@colspan[.=&apos;1&apos;] | @rowspan[.=&apos;1&apos;]"></xsl:template>
    <!-- remove well known Microsoft Word classes -->
    <xsl:template match="@class[.=&apos;MsoNormal&apos;] | @class[.=&apos;MsoTableGrid&apos;]"></xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```